# php - What error reporting level I should use on end user website, which is complete

Tags: php, exception, logging, error-handling

What is the most convenient way of error reporting in finished website? I would like to still log exceptions and errors to external file. I definitely don't want the user to see anything more than "Error: something went wrong, we are lookin into it".

Does my try - catch work and can I log my Exceptions if I set:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: use error pages
and settings in your php.ini as 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(0);

Comment: @SandipPingle I think you have it the wrong way around. On live sites you would want to *hide* errors (i.e. *not* display them), but error reporting should be turned *on* so that you have a log of errors when they do occur.

Comment: So `display_errors(0);` is what i want?

Comment: You could use a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). That way you can choose which errors to display or not and which ones to log.

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` file you should hide errors:

```
display_errors = Off
```

If you want to know about any errors that occur (you should care) you should turn on error logging:

```
log_errors = On
```

How to set error reporting depends on what errors you want to know about. Ideally you should want to know about everything (maybe except errors about deprecated stuff; if the website is already done then you should have fixed any such errors). See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) for more information.

```
; Show everything except deprecated errors
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

And then there are a few more things you can set:

```
; It makes little sense to have this on
html_errors = Off

; Set this to where your log file should be stored
error_log = /path/to/log/file.log

; Maybe more, see link below...
```

You can see some [more options here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

Restart your server after making changes to `php.ini`.